# Add an image to the front of an input field

Tags: html, css

I want to add an image to the front of an input field, like you see on login panels where it may show an icon of a user at the front of the user input field. However all my google searches return are adding background images to input fields.

Does anybody know of any tutorials or have an example of how it is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in a div put the background image on the div.

```
.input_wrapper{background:url('myimage.png');}
input{background:none}
```